# Python JSON returning None value (Telegram API)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, telegram

I am trying to return the user id of new members who join a telegram group, I can get the JSON data but I cannot retrieve values from a level deeper:

code:

```
def new_chat_members(self, bot, update):
        print(update)
        print(update['message'])
        print(update['message']['from'])
        print(update['message'].get('from'))
```

So the first `print(update)` returns me data, the second `print(update['message']['from'])` returns me data too, however when I want to return the third print, I get a return value of none. The last print returns me an error.

The type of the first and second print is:

```
<class 'telegram.update.Update'>
<class 'telegram.message.Message'>
```

Output for the first print:

```
{'update_id': 130834599, 'message': {'message_id': 193, 'date': 1574900654, 'chat': {'id': -1001323635373, 'type': 'supergroup', 'title': 'testbot'}, 'entities': [], 'caption_entities': [], 'photo': [], 'new_chat_members': [{'id': 677494285, 'first_name': 'Mahdi', 'is_bot': False, 'last_name': 'Khan', 'username': 'Samstestacc', 'language_code': 'en'}], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'delete_chat_photo': False, 'group_chat_created': False, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'from': {'id': 677494285, 'first_name': 'Mahdi', 'is_bot': False, 'last_name': 'Khan', 'username': 'Samstestacc', 'language_code': 'en'}}, '_effective_message': {'message_id': 193, 'date': 1574900654, 'chat': {'id': -1001323635373, 'type': 'supergroup', 'title': 'testbot'}, 'entities': [], 'caption_entities': [], 'photo': [], 'new_chat_members': [{'id': 677494285, 'first_name': 'Mahdi', 'is_bot': False, 'last_name': 'Khan', 'username': 'Samstestacc', 'language_code': 'en'}], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'delete_chat_photo': False, 'group_chat_created': False, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'from': {'id': 677494285, 'first_name': 'Mahdi', 'is_bot': False, 'last_name': 'Khan', 'username': 'Samstestacc', 'language_code': 'en'}}}
```

Output for the second print:

```
{'message_id': 188, 'date': 1574900008, 'chat': {'id': -1001323635373, 'type': 'supergroup', 'title': 'testbot'}, 'entities': [], 'caption_entities': [], 'photo': [], 'new_chat_members': [{'id': 677494285, 'first_name': 'Mahdi', 'is_bot': False, 'last_name': 'Khan', 'username': 'Samstestacc', 'language_code': 'en'}], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'delete_chat_photo': False, 'group_chat_created': False, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'from': {'id': 677494285, 'first_name': 'Mahdi', 'is_bot': False, 'last_name': 'Khan', 'username': 'Samstestacc', 'language_code': 'en'}}
```

Could someone help me fix this and reply why I am getting a none output. Thanks

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get' - @RajithThennakoon

Comment: could you post the `update` data as well. if `update['message']` is a dictionary both `update['message']['from']` and `update['message'].get('from')` should work

Comment: @RajithThennakoon I updated the outputs, please check. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As telegram source here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/message.py) ,there is a `to_dict` method,which you can get the dictionary from the Message class.I think this is what you can do.

```
def new_chat_members(self, bot, update):

        message_dictionary = update['message'].to_dict()
        print(message_dictionary.get('from'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either extend `dict` in your `telegram.update.Update` and `telegram.update.Message` classes, something like:

Make sure you use the dict syntax to add your properties...

```py
class Update(dict):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self['message'] = message
```

or you can implement a get method yourself:

```py
class Update:
    def get(self, key):
        if hasattr(self, key):
            return getattr(self, key)
```